# Учебники для углубленного изучения C++

Tags: c++, linux, книги

Здравствуйте.
Пишу на С++. Прочитал (и изучил) учебник Крупника. Не хочу на этом останавливаться - ищу что учить дальше. Подскажите учебники, по которым можно было бы более углубленно учить С++. 
Принимаю любые ответы (как со ссылками, так и просто названия). Желательно на русском.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Comment: боже мой, не минусуйте, я был молод и глуп

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется изучать современный C++, то русским книгами тут не обойтись.

Если понимания зыка есть, но хочется глубже, тогда пора приступать к Страуструпу:
[The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321563840) , [здесь](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/09/05/cpp_programming_lang_4ed.aspx) можно прочитать мою рецензию на книгу. Закончив с основами языка, предлагаю перейти к более глубокому знанию стандартной библиотеки. Для этого есть прекрасная книга: [The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/09/05/cpp_programming_lang_4ed.aspx), моя [рецензия](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/02/04/cpp_standard_lib_2nd.aspx) на книгу тоже присутствует.

Когда эти книги позади, можно взяться за книгу Скотта Майерса: [Effective Modern C++](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491903996). Книга тоже хороша и дополняет две предыдущие. У Майерса есть ещё 3 книги, но я не буду их советовать, т.к. не уверен, что советы в них всё ещё актуальны. Если захотите, Вы легко найдёте список его книг.

Ну и напоследок, есть ещё одна книга, которую можно посоветовать тем, кто хочет глубже понять современный C++: [C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933988770). Моя [рецензия](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/10/03/cpp_concurrency_in_action.aspx). Если я не ошибаюсь, то эта книга выходила на русском языке.

Конечно, это не весь список того, что можно было бы почитать, но Вам и этого надолго хватит.

Comment: Отметил этот вопрос дублем к общему списку. Вам наверняка есть что дополнить — посмотрите, пожалуйста. [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263)

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж почувствовали понимание книги Страуструпа, то пора начинать читать что нибудеь более глубокое. Попробуйте [это](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/85559/) и [это](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6089823/)(не читал, но говорят более дружелюбна для начинающих).

Почитайте труды Герберта Шилдта. Тоже очень хороший автор.